# Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/servlet/jsp/JspWriter

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee, jenkins, sonarqube-4.5

I get the below error when sonar analysis is being done

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.6:sonar (default-cli) on project woo-parent: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file **javax/servlet/jsp/JspWriter**

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.6:sonar (default-cli) on project : Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/servlet/jsp/JspWriter -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.6:sonar (default-cli) on project: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/servlet/jsp/JspWriter
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/servlet/jsp/JspWriter
at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.bootstrap.ExceptionHandling.handle(ExceptionHandling.java:41)
at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.bootstrap.RunnerBootstraper.execute(RunnerBootstraper.java:139)
at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.SonarMojo.execute(SonarMojo.java:132)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/servlet/jsp/JspWriter
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:412)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.typeresolution.PMDASMClassLoader.loadClass(PMDASMClassLoader.java:62)
at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.symboltable.TypeSet$FullyQualifiedNameResolver.resolve(TypeSet.java:222)
at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.symboltable.TypeSet.findClass(TypeSet.java:265)
at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.symboltable.SourceFileScope.resolveType(SourceFileScope.java:55)
at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.symboltable.ClassScope.determineParameterTypes(ClassScope.java:217)
at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.symboltable.ClassScope.findVariableHere(ClassScope.java:142)
at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.symboltable.AbstractJavaScope.contains(AbstractJavaScope.java:33)
at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.symboltable.Search.searchUpward(Search.java:45)
at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.symboltable.Search.searchUpward(Search.java:49)
at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.symboltable.Search.searchUpward(Search.java:49)
at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.symboltable.Search.execute(Search.java:24)
at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.symboltable.OccurrenceFinder.visit(OccurrenceFinder.java:26)
at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.ASTPrimaryExpression.jjtAccept(ASTPrimaryExpression.java:22)
at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.AbstractJavaNode.childrenAccept(AbstractJavaNode.java:55)
at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.JavaParserVisitorAdapter.visit(JavaParserVisitorAdapter.java:9)
at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.JavaParserVisitorAdapter.visit(JavaParserVisitorAdapter.java:372)
at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.ASTStatementExpression.jjtAccept(ASTStatementExpression.java:22)
at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.AbstractJavaNode.childrenAccept(AbstractJavaNode.java:55)
at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.JavaParserVisitorAdapter.visit(JavaParserVisitorAdapter.java:9)
at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.JavaParserVisitorAdapter.visit(JavaParserVisitorAdapter.java:348)
at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.ASTStatement.jjtAccept(ASTStatement.java:22)
at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.AbstractJavaNode.childrenAccept(AbstractJavaNode.java:55)
at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.JavaParserVisitorAdapter.visit(JavaParserVisitorAdapter.java:9)
at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.JavaParserVisitorAdapter.visit(JavaParserVisitorAdapter.java:360)
at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.ASTBlockStatement.jjtAccept(ASTBlockStatement.java:22)
at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.AbstractJavaNode.childrenAccept(AbstractJavaNode.java:55)
at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.JavaParserVisitorAdapter.visit(JavaParserVisitorAdapter.java:9)
at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.JavaParserVisitorAdapter.visit(JavaParserVisitorAdapter.java:356)
at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.ASTBlock.jjtAccept(ASTBlock.java:22)
at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.AbstractJavaNode.childrenAccept(AbstractJavaNode.java:55)
at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.JavaParserVisitorAdapter.visit(JavaParserVisitorAdapter.java:9)
at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.JavaParserVisitorAdapter.visit(JavaParserVisitorAdapter.java:180)
at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.ASTMethodDeclaration.jjtAccept(ASTMethodDeclaration.java:25)
at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.AbstractJavaNode.childrenAccept(AbstractJavaNode.java:55)
at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.JavaParserVisitorAdapter.visit(JavaParserVisitorAdapter.java:9)
at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.JavaParserVisitorAdapter.visit(JavaParserVisitorAdapter.java:45)
at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.ASTClassOrInterfaceBodyDeclaration.jjtAccept(ASTClassOrInterfaceBodyDeclaration.java:41)
at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.AbstractJavaNode.childrenAccept(AbstractJavaNode.java:55)
at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.JavaParserVisitorAdapter.visit(JavaParserVisitorAdapter.java:9)
at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.JavaParserVisitorAdapter.visit(JavaParserVisitorAdapter.java:41)
at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.ASTClassOrInterfaceBody.jjtAccept(ASTClassOrInterfaceBody.java:22)
at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.AbstractJavaNode.childrenAccept(AbstractJavaNode.java:55)
at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.JavaParserVisitorAdapter.visit(JavaParserVisitorAdapter.java:9)
at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.JavaParserVisitorAdapter.visit(JavaParserVisitorAdapter.java:17)
at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.ASTClassOrInterfaceDeclaration.jjtAccept(ASTClassOrInterfaceDeclaration.java:26)
at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.AbstractJavaNode.childrenAccept(AbstractJavaNode.java:55)
at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.JavaParserVisitorAdapter.visit(JavaParserVisitorAdapter.java:9)
at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.JavaParserVisitorAdapter.visit(JavaParserVisitorAdapter.java:156)
at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.ASTTypeDeclaration.jjtAccept(ASTTypeDeclaration.java:36)
at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.AbstractJavaNode.childrenAccept(AbstractJavaNode.java:55)
at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.JavaParserVisitorAdapter.visit(JavaParserVisitorAdapter.java:9)
at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.JavaParserVisitorAdapter.visit(JavaParserVisitorAdapter.java:136)
at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.ASTCompilationUnit.jjtAccept(ASTCompilationUnit.java:42)
at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.symboltable.SymbolFacade.initializeWith(SymbolFacade.java:16)
at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.AbstractJavaHandler$4.start(AbstractJavaHandler.java:79)
at net.sourceforge.pmd.SourceCodeProcessor.symbolFacade(SourceCodeProcessor.java:100)
at net.sourceforge.pmd.SourceCodeProcessor.processSource(SourceCodeProcessor.java:139)
at net.sourceforge.pmd.SourceCodeProcessor.processSourceCode(SourceCodeProcessor.java:76)
at net.sourceforge.pmd.SourceCodeProcessor.processSourceCode(SourceCodeProcessor.java:43)
at org.sonar.plugins.pmd.PmdTemplate.process(PmdTemplate.java:83)
at org.sonar.plugins.pmd.PmdExecutor.executeRules(PmdExecutor.java:119)
at org.sonar.plugins.pmd.PmdExecutor.executePmd(PmdExecutor.java:89)
at org.sonar.plugins.pmd.PmdExecutor.execute(PmdExecutor.java:75)
at org.sonar.plugins.pmd.PmdSensor.analyse(PmdSensor.java:67)
at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.executeSensor(SensorsExecutor.java:79)
at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:70)
at org.sonar.batch.phases.PhaseExecutor.execute(PhaseExecutor.java:119)
at org.sonar.batch.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:194)
at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:92)
at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77)
at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:233)
at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:228)
at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:226)
at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:226)
at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:221)
at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:92)
at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77)
at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.scan(ScanTask.java:64)
at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:51)
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:125)
at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:92)
at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77)
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BootstrapContainer.executeTask(BootstrapContainer.java:173)
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:95)
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:67)
at org.sonar.runner.batch.IsolatedLauncher.execute(IsolatedLauncher.java:48)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:87)
at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:102)
at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:100)
at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.bootstrap.RunnerBootstraper.execute(RunnerBootstraper.java:135)
... 22 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
Sonar analysis completed: FAILURE
Build step 'Sonar' changed build result to FAILURE
Build step 'Sonar' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

This is similar to the bug mentioned [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/opencmsmoddev/bugs/12/)

i tried different answers mentioned in similar questions on Stackoverflow but it doesnt resolve this issue and the build is in failed state on Jenkins

Earlier this used to be a warning but now it has become a blocker.

Thank you.

Comment: Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: if i deactivate pmd rules in sonar quality profile then i donot get this error, but if i acitvate the pmd rules then i get the above error.